# (private static reference vs private reference) performance

Tags: c#, performance

Ok so let's say we have a factory that produces instances of objects. The instances that this factory produces have a dependency on one reference.

I am trying to understand if there is any difference in declaring this reference in objects as private or as private static. What C# is doing behind the scene. Does declaring the reference static is more efficient in a data store manner.

Example code:

So we are talking about this

```
public class ShoesFactory {
    
    public ShoesFactory(Material soleMaterial){ // contractor
       ShoesOfTypeA.SetSoleMaterial(soleMaterial)
    }

    public ShoesOfTypeA GetShoesOfTypeA() {
       return new ShoesOfTypeA ();
    }
}
```

```
public class ShoesOfTypeA {
   private static Material soleMaterial;

   public static SetSoleMaterial(soleMaterial){
      ShoesOfTypeA.soleMaterial = soleMaterial;
   }

   
}
```

Vs this

```
public class ShoesFactory {
    
    private Material soleMaterial;
    public ShoesFactory(Material soleMaterial){ // contractor
       this.soleMaterial=soleMaterial;
    }

    public ShoesOfTypeA GetShoesOfTypeA() {
       return new ShoesOfTypeA (soleMaterial);
    }
}
```

```
public class ShoesOfTypeA {
   private Material soleMaterial;

   public ShoesOfTypeA(soleMaterial) { //constructor
      this.soleMaterial = soleMaterial;
   }
}
```

Edit :
As John Alexiou said in the comments initializing a field on the constructor of a different class is violates the principle of encapsulation so we moved initialization out of contractors

The question here is not about how to follow the SOLID design principles but
what is the performance differences of the above codes :)

Comment: Couldn't you run a performance profiler (like e.g. [the VS built-in one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019), [the one from Red Gate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) or [the one from Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and compare your conde snippets?

Comment: Please write valid `C#` code. `private static soleMaterial` isn't valid because it lacks a type.

Comment: I don't think that performance is the main concern. Static or not has more important consequences

Comment: Both code snippets are terrible because you initialize a field on the constructor _of a different class_. This violates the principle of encapsulation. Also, look into `Lazy<T>` for a type if you want lazy intialization.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou You are right. we can move the initialization of static reference into a static setter that would be called from the factory only once. Thanks for the answer! I definitely will take a look into Lazy<T>.

Comment: Thanks @UweKeim. I will definitely take a look into that

Comment: @DanielMann there is questions in this forum about what is a constructor. And people really answer thems. There are people that they don't know that a constructor is.. and people that don't know how to proper profile something. If you don't know what c# is doing under the hood the is no point to downvote. Because there are people they know

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not performance, but design at this point.

I propose you have a single `Shoe` class with a property designating the type of shoe, and a single factory method to generate the shoes. Also, the material can be read on demand using a `Lazy<Material>` field, which calls some method (delegate) when it is first accessed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new ShoeFactory(ReadMaterial);
        var b = factory.GetShoesOfType(ShoeType.B);
    }
    static Material ReadMaterial()
    {
        return new Material();
    }
}

public class Material
{
}
public enum ShoeType
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public sealed class Shoe
{
    public Shoe(Material material, ShoeType type)
    {
        Material=material;
        Type=type;
    }

    public Material Material { get; }
    public ShoeType Type { get; }
}

public class ShoeFactory
{
    private readonly Lazy<Material> soleMaterial;

    public ShoeFactory(Func<Material> materialFactory)
    {
        this.soleMaterial=new Lazy<Material>(materialFactory);
    }

    public Shoe GetShoesOfType(ShoeType type)
    {
        return new Shoe(soleMaterial.Value, type);
    }
}
```

The above design is straight forward, flexible and if you were to ask me about performance, like any other modern application the slowerst part is initializing classes, and by keeping the class structure simple you are helping the compiler do the appropriate optimizations on its own.